Retrosynthesis of saffron pyranone from acetone and acetic acid
I have an assignment on the retrosynthesis of a lactone (4,4,6‐trimethyloxan‐2‐one) from acetone and acetic acid as precursors:

And I came up with the following scheme:

I initially went for a 1,4-addition of acetic acid, which is impossible because the α-carbon of acetic acid is not nucleophile, so I went for an esterification to get an ester enolate (nucleophile) with the right basic conditions.
But I think my teacher has another solution in mind. So, is there another (maybe simpler) way to synthesize the lactone from these precursors? And I'm sure if there's no incompatibility between certain functions and some reaction conditions.

Your approach looks reasonable, but rather elaborate. I think it could be done in two steps. Remember that CH3COOH an acid by itself and this is an opportunity rather than obstacle.

In trans esterification, esters can react with alcohols to form new esters, see Wikipedia So maybe you could reduce the last two steps to one

@CuckooBeats Oh, this one's a no-brainer, but as I mentions before, esterifying it in the first place is a waste of time.

@CuckooBeats Oh yes I was focusing on the 1,4 addition step so I missed the transesterification shortcut. I’ll edit it when I come home. Thanks !

@Mithoron So the acetic acid can react in the 1,4 addition without being esterified ? Because I can’t think of something else than 1,4 addition because I have to make that C-C bond between the acetic acid and the aldol. And I don’t see how the acid properties of acetic acid can help making that C-C bond. But I must be missing something.

@CuckooBeats For the retrosynthesis problem ? If so, no sorry, my teacher probably came up with it on its own and there’s nothing more than what I showed. But I can share the correction from my teacher once I’ll have it.

@Mithoron please give another hint, thought yesterday about it. I could only get an isomer of the lactone (aldol condensation then esterification and again intramolecular aldol condensation)

I'm not sure it would work, but it looks like one pot reaction. Add acetic acid and ketone to condense acetone, then get addition, perhaps with stronger acid, finally neutralise and reduce.

Your synthesis is on the right track but the anion of an acetate ester, say ethyl acetate (pKa=~25), is not going to undergo conjugate addition to mesityl oxide 2. The anion needs to be more nucleophilic. The anion of diethyl malonate (pKa=~13) adds to mesityl oxide 2 because it is utilized in the preparation of dimedone (5,5-dimethylcyclohexan-1,3-dione). But there is no convenient way to produce malonic ester from your starting materials. Acetoacetic ester (AAE; pKa=~11), from the self-condensation in base of ethyl acetate, is another candidate for addition but it would require deacylation in aqueous alkali of the β-ketoester adduct. The deacylation occurs in disubstituted acetoacetic esters but less likely here.
I am unsure what your teacher has in mind but if I were asking the question, I would ask how can the saffron lactone 6 be formed from acetone alone.
While mesityl oxide 3 is formed in base, further condenasation with a third acetone does occur to form isophorone 3. Here the conjugate addition of the enolate of acetone (pKa=~20) is possible followed by an intermolecular aldol condensation. Excision of $\ce{C2}$ can occur via ozonolysis followed by oxidative workup ($\ce{H2O2, CrO3, KMnO4, HIO4}$). $\ce{NaBH4}$ reduction of ketoacid 4 affords hydroxyacid 5 which is cyclized to the saffron lactone 6.

